# cannot place order using my account after upgrading the magento version 1.7 to 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, orders, onepage-checkout, customer-account

cannot place order using my account after upgrading the magento version 1.7 to 1.9.2
can anyone help me out.
am not getting any error but it just stay on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Given information is not enough to give solution. You can debug your problem as follows.

Some of check point may help you.

- Enable Magento Log - Check system.log, exception.log and php error log
- Enable display_errors in index.php - this will show you error in
  response text
- Debug your checkout ajax request from firebug console/net panel, this will help you to find out if any javascript error.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer..it is helped me to fix my issue.

go to the below path :
**app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml**

find the , inside the script you already have these :

review = new Review('getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));

replace this with below code :

review = new Review('getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));

This means you just want to add the form keys.
hope this will help anybody.